# What is "Type mismatch" and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, syntax-error, bukkit, type-mismatch

How to fix this error?

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Block

I see it at this line:

```
for (Block b : blocksToSkip){
```

Here is the full code.

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.NORMAL, ignoreCancelled=true)
public void onEntityExplode(EntityExplodeEvent ev){
    ArrayList blocksToSkip = new ArrayList();
    Location rootLoc = ev.getLocation();
    if (!SkyMagic.IsInIslandWorld(rootLoc)) return;
    for (Block b : ev.blockList()){
        Location loc = b.getLocation();
        IslandData data = SkyMagic.GetIslandAt(loc);
        if ((data != null) && (data.owner != null)){
            blocksToSkip.add(b);
        }
    }
    for (Block b : blocksToSkip){
        ev.blockList().remove(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw types. `blocksToSkip` should be a `ArrayList<Block>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **raw type**:

```
ArrayList blocksToSkip
```

Java expects everything, not only the `Block` type.
Therefore, you need a **type cast**.

```
ArrayList blocksToSkip = new ArrayList();

// Rest of your code

for (Object b : blocksToSkip){
    ev.blockList().remove( (Block)b );
}
```

Note it is discouraged to use raw types.
You should **parameterize** instead.

```
ArrayList<Block> blocksToSkip = new ArrayList<Block>();
```