# How to create a selfexisting button in one line in java?

Tags: java, jbutton

How to create this:

```
JButton b = new JButton("text").addActionListener(e -> classX.addNewTest()));
buttons.add(b);
```

in one line? I tryed this:

```
panel.add(b = new JButton("text").addActionListener(e -> classX.addNewTest()));
```

But how could I do it whitout creating a "b"?

Comment: Do you need `b` somewhere else? If not, try `panel.add(new JButton("text").addActionListener(e -> classX.addNewTest()));` without declaring b.

Comment: @ppasler `addActionListener()` returns `void` (up to Java 9), so this would not work - the same reason it did not work for the code posted in the question

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger indeed you are right, my bad.

Comment: @Tobiasz - just out of curiosity, why must it be one line? Three fundamental operations in one line: button creation, handling of action and adding to panel. Easier to understand and maintain if on different lines...just MHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do that in one line, you could extend the JButton class and add the listener in a instance initializer:

```
    panel.add(new JButton("text") {{ addActionListener(e -> classX.addNewTest()); }} );
```

I would **not recommend** doing that: it is very hard to understand, almost code obfuscation, and it is creating a subclass of JButton without really extending its functionality at all.  See [What is Double Brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/85421).

A better approach could be to write a method to create buttons - I do this for most components:

```
    panel.add(createJButton("test", e -> classX.addNewTest()));

...

private JButton createJButton(String text, ActionListener listener) {
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    // more customization if needed
    return button;
}
```

Comment: To repeat and ephasisze what you said: **I would not recommend doing that**. It's really odd...

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong **this is not possible with one line**!

**Why?**

Because there are different type so for example :
 `jButton.addActionListener(Action)` don't return any thing a `void` so you could not add a void type to a List which take a `JButton` type.

and you can get this error : `'void' type not allowed here` and [type-mismatch-cannot convert typeX to typeY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81392/java-why-do-i-receive-the-error-message-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-int-to-b)

[What is "Type mismatch" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325278/what-is-type-mismatch-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I know that `jButton.addActionListener(Action)` returns void. I'm just looking for a clever way to do it (even in a diferent form) in one line. But thank you for answering, if there is no other option I will just use two lines ;/

Answer (score 0):

You may also look into `Action`:

```
    JButton b;
    new JPanel().add(b=new JButton(new AbstractAction("Click Me"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //
        }
    }));
```